# Event management screen is not showing all tabs

Tags: civievent

Is there a setting somewhere that prevents an Admin to see other usual tabs when dealing with events?

[image]

Comment: never seen that.

Comment: Are you using https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-advanced-events ?  That can hide some tabs for events.

Comment: that was it! thanks Aidan. I'd totally forgotten this setting :-(

Comment: Good! - so I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be caused by https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-advanced-events  This extension can hide tabs that are not wanted on the event management pages.